# What would be the first things you do to find out about an MYSQL environment you are taking over?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-workbench

I am new to DBA role, and wanted to know if there was any commands (or free software) that come with Mysql 5.5 (master/slave/slave) replication to quickly get familiar with
the database, and also making sure my.cnf is set up with the correct parameters.

Comment: maybe break this out into a few separate questions by posting your configs, describing your workload, and asking for help identifying potential areas of weakness in the system.

also, look for documentation from the last person.

Comment: @swasheck - that's almost an answer in itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pt-mysql-summary](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-mysql-summary.html) tool from [Percona toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/) gives you a very nice overview of your running server.

It will tell you stuff like what the major config params are set to, what technologies ara available in your server, take a 10 second status sample, analyze your schema etc.

Also worth to run [pt-duplicate-key-checker](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-duplicate-key-checker.html) at least once, to detect redundant keys.

I'm authoring the [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) tool for MySQL, which also offers some diagnostics: the [redundant_keys](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/redundant_keys.html) view is parallel to pt-duplicate-key-checker; the [data_size_per_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/data_size_per_schema.html) view will tell you, well, the datasize per schema; the [auto_increment_columns](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/auto_increment_columns.html) view will tell you about "free space" in your AUTO_INCREMENT columns; and more.

Watching the processes as they go, using `innotop` or the old-timer `mytop` is also worthwhile: get to know the processes that run most, the longest etc.